# parsing: sighed with relief that .

Tags: sentence-structure, parsing

I'm wondering whether "that it was all over" is a clausal object of "sigh" or an appositive clause attached to "relief."

> She sighed with relief **that it was all over**.

Comment: I don't think that _sigh_ can take a "that" clause, so it must be attached to _relief_. I would call it a complement (or "object", if you will) of _relief_.

Comment: The issue is actually more complex than it suggests at first glance. Can "with relief that . . ." be used with any other verb than "sigh"? If it forms a unit, can it occur sentence-initially, as most modifiers do?

Comment: It's nothing do with the verb or with "with". _Relief_ can take a "that" clause. The iWeb corpus has 7633 instances of _relief that_, and by inspection most of them are this structure.

Comment: Can you show me another verb that can be used with "with relief that . . ."?

Comment: OK, I think I get where your'e coming from, @Apollyon. Most sequences of _(verb) with relief that_, the _that_ will go with the "verb", for example _He heard with relief that they had not gone_. But this is because the _heard_ readily takes _that_, so this is more easily read as _heard ... that_. Examples from the corpus where this is not so are _sobbing with relief that their loved one survived_, _I was filled with relief that the car had held up all day_, and _laughs nervously but with relief that she finally made it._  Where there is not another verb to grab the "that", _relief_ takes it.

Comment: Is it okay to say "Joanne called Peter with relief that she had passed the exam"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a syntactic point of view, both are valid. This is borne out by this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=with%20relief%20that%2Csighed%20that&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwith%20relief%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csighed%20that%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwith%20relief%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csighed%20that%3B%2Cc0), which shows that both "sighed that" and "with relief that" do occur, however "with relief that" is very much more common, and most of the instances of "sighed that" occur across sentence boundaries, for example "sighed. That". Here is one of the very few sentences where a that-clause does modify **sigh**.

> A young Muslim man sighed that he had given away 300 dalasi as saliboo during Tobaski . -*The Best Hand is the Hand that Always Gives, Marloes Janson 2002*

Looking at the semantics, in your sentence it is clear that the sigh is because she is relieved, and the relief is because it is all over. The that-clause therefore relates to the relief, not to the sigh.

Comment: But can "with relief that . . ." be used with any other verb?

Comment: If it forms a unit, can it occur sentence-initially, as most modifiers do?

Comment: @Apollyon yes it can. You can use it with see, cry, weep, remember, realise.....

Comment: It could in principle occur sentence- initially, but I have not seen any examples of that. It is possible to find examples without a that-clause, like this one: "With relief, he felt his muscles contract and release as he moved downhill."

Comment: How about "Sarah called John with relief that she had passed the exam"?

Comment: @Apollyon no, you can't. You can only use it for things that make you relieved (see, remember, realise) or things that you do directly because you are relieved (sigh, cry, weep...). Calling somebody is an indirect action: there is a thought process between the relief and the call. "Sarah was relieved that she passed the exam, so she called John".